# Some way to know the instant a process launched

Tags: c++, winapi, process, timer, message

I just want to know every time a process is launched on win32.  Like recieve a message.  Instead of a timer thats like every x secs to check process list.

Comment: hook the launch process functions ;)

Comment: WMI can send you events when processes start. I think a CBT hook could also be used.

Comment: @Gam Why would you choose such a solution when the system provides official ways. And hooking process launch is presumably seriously tricky.